# Two modal pop up but but don't allow to First popup selectable

Tags: html, asp.net, ajax, css

I have two modal popup extender of ajax on First modal pop up extender
, I call second modal pop up but First modal pop up is selectable ,
so How to don't allow to select modal popup...is there any solution...THanks!!!!!!

aspx=>

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtenderReporting" runat="server" PopupControlID="PanelReporting" TargetControlID="LinkButtonReporting" 
  BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" Enabled="false"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Comment: could you include to your question the code example?

Comment: added aspx code in que please see and revert .. Thanks @Ihor Lavs